# How can i set the event OnFocusOut on a EditText?

Tags: android, focus, android-event

I cant find the way to get the event "focus exiting from a edittext" (neather "focus entering an edittext"). I've found the event OnFocusChange, but it is called both the times, entering and exiting the edit, and i want my function called by that event to be called once.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnFocusChange` method has two parameters, second parameter is `boolean hasFocus` isn't it what you need?
If it is `true` it means entering focus and you can write your code there.

Let me know if I misunderstood